# Created wifi network not showing on other devices

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04

i run ubuntu 14.04. my wireless is working fine. but when i create a wifi network on my laptop, it creates successfully, but other devices cant see it even when i try to connect to a hidden network. How can i make the wire less show successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the 'Create New Wi-Fi Network' option in the context menu of network-manager? For some reason, that option is a little bugged. I've not been able to get it working either.

Anyway, I managed to share my ethernet network connection via WiFi to other devices using this method:

1. Click on network-manager and then on 'Edit Connections'
2. Create a new WiFi connection and give it an SSID, e.g. `WiFi Hotspot`.
3. Switch to the 'Wi-Fi Security' tab, choose WPA & WPA2 Personal, and give your hotspot a password.
4. Switch to the IPv4 tab and change the method to 'Shared to other computers' option.
5. Save and close the connection settings window, and try connecting to your hotspot on your other device(s). It should work and give them internet access through your computer.